# JBoss Unable to load deployments but app is running

Tags: jar, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

Hi In my jboss deployed an app and couldn't figure out what is wrong with this recent deployment. App is deployed successfully and it works fine but just the jboss console throws the following error.

when i try to add the new ear file, it shows the success message and immediately shows the error message "Unable to load deployments" and throws the following error message in logs. any suggestions are helpful...thanks!

```
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([
("deployment" => "APP1_00_EAR.ear"),
("subsystem" => "jpa"),
("hibernate-persistence-unit" => "APP1_00_EAR.ear#BSS"),
("entity-cache" => "au.ab.app1.business.entity.BBssDesk")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.getSecondLevelCacheRegion(CacheImpl.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getSecondLevelCacheRegion(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(ConcurrentStatisticsImpl.java:334)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.management.HibernateEntityCacheStatistics.getStatistics(HibernateEntityCacheStatistics.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.management.HibernateEntityCacheStatistics$4.invoke(HibernateEntityCacheStatistics.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.management.HibernateAbstractStatistics.getValue(HibernateAbstractStatistics.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.ManagementResourceDefinition$1.handle(ManagementResourceDefinition.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.ManagementResourceDefinition$AbstractMetricsHandler.executeRuntimeStep(ManagementResourceDefinition.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractRuntimeOnlyHandler$1.execute(AbstractRuntimeOnlyHandler.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:982)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:450)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1402)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:418)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:263)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:221)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:287)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:244)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:330)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Comment: Looks like your configuration is wrong either in your PU or in your server JPA configuration

Comment: surprisingly the app works fine, but the console is unable to load the deployments, and throws this error in logs. where do i check the JPA config? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using 7.1.2 version of JBoss EAP (which has this issue), upgrading to 7.1.3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are encountering issue reported in [jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10260) This issue is encountered when JBoss API's try to read information about deployed application. This issue is fixed in latest wildfly release.

Comment: Im using JBoss EAP 7.1.2 version on RHEL, if this is fixed in latest version, may i know what version is it? Thanks!

Comment: 7.1.3 should have the fix